# Arrays help trying to get output

Tags: java

hi guys need help trying to output the code for this program heres what i have so far.
Please work with me here as i am new to Arrays.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class TestArray {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

  for (int i=1; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
    intArray[i] = i;
  } 

  for (int i=1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[0] = intArray[4];
    i = intArray[2];
    intArray[i] = intArray[2];
    intArray[i++] = intArray[9];
    intArray[9%2] = intArray[6];
    intArray[i+=3] = intArray[7];
    intArray[7] = intArray[i-=1];
    intArray[i] = intArray[i--];
    intArray[9] = (int)Math.pow(intArray[9], intArray[2]);
    intArray[--i] = intArray[++i];    
  }

  for(int myArray : intArray){    
    System.out.println(myArray);
  }

 }
}
```

Keep getting an error when trying to run

Comment: I assume that you want to iterate over the array.  The trouble is that the logic in your loop is horrid, is full of side-effects, and is unclear to the point of being garish.  No one would ever do something like this.

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. As @scottb stated, "the logic in your loop is horrid.".  What if your desired output.  Post that and you will definitely get some help

Comment: Thanks but i seem to have figured it out. this was code that was assigned to me to show the output, did not produce the code myself! however i made a few changes and it seems to be running. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes are manipulating with data in array. NOT recommended as array not grow here. If you want such cases use Collection's ArrayList.